# Moving Row from From "Response Sheet" to "Temp" Sheet, then value paste the same data from "Temp" Sheet to "FinalData" Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am searching the solution since last 20 days on internet without any luck. I know a little bit of VBA but I just cannot write a single line in Google JavaScripts. I humbly request all experts here to please help me out.

I have three Sheets within same google workbook; namely:

1. Form Response [connected to google form],
2. Temp, and
3. FinalData

When the form is submitted, I want to **cut and paste** one row at a time from "Form Response" sheet to "Temp" sheet.

"Temp" sheet has additional columns where `arrayformula` is applied for some nested complex calculations. Once `arrayformulas` have finished calculation, I want to **cut and value paste** that row from "Temp" sheet to "FinalData" sheet in next blank row.

Then, this entire procedure should be repeated (looped) until all filled rows are moved from "Form Response" sheet.

This way, I will get value pasted data of "Form Response" sheet with added columns in "FinalData" sheet.

**Please note** that I do **NOT** want all rows of "Form Response" cut pasted at once. This will jeopardize my purpose because `arrayformula` is dependent on complex nested calculations for each row where unique value is unavailable.

Comment: This would be easier to visualize if we could see your spreadsheet.  Personally, I would use an onFormSubmit trigger and move submitted form data from the event object to the temp  sheet.  I prefer not interacting programmatically with the linked sheets if possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve].

Comment: Do you already have a sheet with Form Responses that you need to update, or is this in anticipation of receiving new submissions. Either way, I don't see the point of the "temp" sheet; why not get the data from the submission, do the calculation, then paste the result into Final. Would you also explain the nature of the calculation that you will carry out on "temp"?